# SCDF Composed task child k8s pods are not deleted on cleanup

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I have composed task based batch app with 3 tasks tied together.
When I start a composed task, there are totally 4 pods gets created. one for parent and 3 child pods.
For example I have a composed app configured like below in SCDF UI
[image]

And the corresponding pods are created as below

```
:~$ kubectl get pods 
vc2311-n1e6j56xxo                       0/1     Completed   0          4m18s
vc2311-vb2csima-gd2exox84d              0/1     Completed   0          2m31s
vc2311-vfr2311-y5e0mqwe2v               0/1     Completed   0          3m1s
vc2311-vfw2311-n4zgemk6z8               0/1     Completed   0          1m2s
```

Once after the execution when I do 'Cleanup' from UI, I see only the parent pod gets deleted and the child pods are not deleted. In above case, only **vc2311-n1e6j56xxo** pod is deleted. Currently we added additional scripts to go and remove those child pods explicitly. I am using spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.10.0. Could you please help to understand why the child pods are not deleted? any additional steps or actions required ?

Comment: Can you try and reproduce with 2.10.3 or 2.11.1?